# XMLHttpRequest.send crashes browser

Tags: xmlhttprequest, web-worker

This code crashes on the send() - only if called in a web worker. Runs fine in the main thread.

```
var  xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', "http://localhost:62178/document?" + msg.url, false);
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
var worker = this;

xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
            // ...
};
xhr.send();
```

No console output, just a browser crash

Answer (score 1):

The open needs to be:

```
xhr.open('GET', "http://localhost:62178/document?" + msg.url, true);
```

Async must be set to true in a web worker.

Comment: I don't believe this is true. In fact, pretty much the only time you *should* be using a synchronous XHR **is** inside a web worker.

Comment: @idbehold Well changing that took it from crashing the session (with no console output) to working fine.

Comment: Well, for one thing you don't need the `xhr.onreadystatechange` handler if your xhr is synchronous. The `xhr.responseText` should be available immediately after `xhr.send()`.